# Converting query with aggregate functions to a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

What I am trying to do is extract what and how many orders are ordered by customers.
I am able to get all the data but what I want is to group it based on a TrackingID unique to each customer, and thus get only one row per customer, regardless of how many items ordered.

The Code I currently have is

```
Select OT.TrackingID As FW_ID
,(  Select
    SUBSTRING(CT.Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', CT.Name) - 1)
    Where LEN(CT.Name) - LEN(REPLACE(CT.Name, ' ', '')) > 0
)   As Forename
,(  Select
    SUBSTRING(CT.Name, CHARINDEX(' ', CT.Name) + 1, 8000)
    Where LEN(CT.Name) - LEN(REPLACE(CT.Name, ' ', '')) > 0
)   As Surname
,(  Select CAST(1 as VARCHAR) + ' p1 male'  
Where OT.ArticleNr = 1
And CT.GroupNr IN (2,5)) As Amount_male_t1
,(  Select CAST(1 as VARCHAR) + ' p1 female'  
Where OT.ArticleNr = 2
And CT.GroupNr IN (2,5)) As Amount_female_t1
,(  Select CAST(1 as VARCHAR) + ' p2 male'  
Where OT.ArticleNr = 1
And CT.GroupNr IN (3,6)) As Amount_male_t2
,(  Select CAST(1 as VARCHAR) + ' p2 female'  
Where OT.ArticleNr = 2
And CT.GroupNr IN (3,6)) As Amount_female_t2

From OrderTable As OT
JOIN CustomerTable As CT
    ON OT.CustomerNr = CT.CustomerNr
JOIN CampaignTable As CT
    ON OT.TrackingID = CT.TrackingID
Where CT.GroupNr IN (2,3,5,6)
And OT.NewOrder = 1
```

An example of what I can get from this is

```
FW_ID      Forename      Surname      Amount_male_t1      Amount_female_t1      Amount_male_t2      Amount_female_t2
101        John          Doe          1 p1 male           NULL                  NULL                NULL
101        John          Doe          NULL                1 p1 female           NULL                NULL
102        Steve         Boss         NULL                NULL                  1 p2 male           NULL
102        Steve         Boss         NULL                NULL                  1 p2 male           NULL
```

And what I want is

```
FW_ID      Forename      Surname      Amount_male_t1      Amount_female_t1      Amount_male_t2      Amount_female_t2
101        John          Doe          1 p1 male           1 p1 female           NULL                NULL
102        Steve         Boss         NULL                NULL                  2 p2 male           NULL
```

Problem is that when I use Group By on OT.TrackingID I get an error when using MAX() on the names due to them being aggregated already and errors when trying to turn the package counters into COUNT() funktions.
Help would be most appreciated.

The joined tables looks something like this

OrderTable:

```
TrackingID      CustomerNr      OrderNr      ArticleNr      NewOrder      OrderDate
101             10054           25           1              1             2014-06-09
101             10054           24           2              1             2014-06-09
102             10036           23           1              1             2014-06-08
102             10036           22           1              1             2014-06-07
103             10044           21           2              0             2014-06-06
```

CustomerTable

```
CustomerNr      Name          Adress        ZipCode      CustomerCreatedDate
10054           John Doe      Upstreet      123456       2013-05-18
10036           Steve Boss    Downstreet    234567       2014-06-07
10044           Eric Cartman  Sidestreet    345678       2014-02-21
```

CampaignTable

```
TrackingID      GroupNr      ProductDescription
101             2            Group 2 & 5 are offered package 1
102             3            Group 3 & 6 are offered package 2
103             5            Group 2 & 5 are offered package 1
```

NOTE: If someone could give advice as to why my question is downvoted that would be most appreciated. I don't quite know what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use a view, as mentioned. You can do this in-line in the query, and it doesn't need to be saved in the schema.

I've made a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40aa7/10/0) to show how this can be done with the sample table data you provided. From here if you wanted to change the representation of the data to a single line, you can just pivot it as shown [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
SELECT SplitNames.Forename, SplitNames.LastName FROM CustomerTable
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT CustomerNr,
  SUBSTRING(CT.Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', CT.Name) - 1) As Forename,
  SUBSTRING(CT.Name, CHARINDEX(' ', CT.Name), LEN(CT.Name) - 1) As LastName
  FROM CustomerTable CT
) SplitNames ON CustomerTable.CustomerNr = SplitNames.CustomerNr
```

In general you should try to use as few subqueries in the select statement as possible, as it makes it impossible to properly aggregate any of your results.

Comment: I played around a bit with your fiddle and this helped me get exactly what I wanted, all in one query. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You could use your query as a view and then use that view for a new query using distinct and count clauses.
I'm sorry, I understand this is not the best solution since it has two steps and maybe could be solve in a better way, but I can't find anything better, at moment, without any example data on a my db.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean "as a view".
Also, I would prefer keeping it down to one single query or some kind of chain/nested solution.

Comment: A sql view is a virtual table. [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp).

CREATE VIEW view_name AS
(_your code here_)

SELECT DISTINCT, COUNT(column) FROM view_name
GROUP BY column

"I would prefer keeping it down to one single query or some kind of chain/nested solution."

Yeah, I understand. I hope someone will give you a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried grouping by the alias at the end? Just try adding:
group by FW_ID
At the end, and see what happens

Comment: Yes Tanner, a Group By alone clashes with the Substring funktions. Possible with the subselects as well.
Anyhow, while it was somewhat tedious, insilenzios suggestion does give the correct result in the end and once I have the View it was quite easy to get what I wanted.
Should I publish my final solution or this answer suffice for future people perhaps?

Comment: If you prefer, instead of the view, you can use the WITH clause. In this way will be created a "runtime view". 

WITH view_name AS (_your code here_) 
SELECT DISTINCT, COUNT(column) FROM view_name GROUP BY column

Comment: It is a good suggestion and it does work but I believe kchris came with an even better solution.
I either case I will keep View and With with me for future reference.